Mail sent through Gmail's API with Python is being identified as spam/phishing
I just learned how to write a Python script that uses Gmail's API to send mails automatically and it works fine except for a couple of issues. First, all the mails sent throught this method have a warning that they might be spam or phishing, which means some servers might block them. Second, the mails sent do not have my signature.
I'm assuming that both are related, possibly because the API is probably not going through the full process of identifying my account and my primary e-mail, but I couldn't figure out a way to make that work.
The method I used is this one: https://thepythoncode.com/article/use-gmail-api-in-python
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: As requested in the comments, here's the actual code:
import os
import pickle

#Gmail API utils
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# for encoding/decoding messages in base64
from base64 import urlsafe_b64decode, urlsafe_b64encode

# for dealing with attachment MIME types
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from mimetypes import guess_type as guess_mime_type

# Request all access (permission to read/send/receive emails, manage the inbox, and more)
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
my_email = 'sample@gmail.com'

def gmail_authenticate():

    creds = None

    # the file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time

    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

        # if there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # save the credentials for the next run
            with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# get the Gmail API service
service = gmail_authenticate()

# Adds the attachment with the given filename to the given message
def add_attachment(message, filename):
    content_type, encoding = guess_mime_type(filename)
    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read().decode(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    message.attach(msg)

def build_message(destination, obj, body, attachments=[]):
    if not attachments:  # no attachments given
        message = MIMEText(body)
        message['to'] = destination
        message['from'] = my_email
        message['subject'] = obj
    else:
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['to'] = destination
        message['from'] = my_email
        message['subject'] = obj
        message.attach(MIMEText(body))
        for filename in attachments:
            add_attachment(message, filename)
    return {'raw': urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}

def send_message(serv, destination, obj, body, attachments=[]):
    return serv.users().messages().send(
        userId="me",
        body=build_message(destination, obj, body, attachments)
    ).execute()

send_message(service, my_email, "Test subject", "This is the body of the e-mail")


Please provide the actual code you are using rather than a link to an external resource. Even if they are the same, please edit the question to include the code.

I thought it would just be easier to post the link because the code is 100 lines long, but I've now edited the question to include the code I used.

Make sure your from-header is ['From'], and not ['from']
